# ggplot: arranging boxplots of multiple y-variables for each group of a continuous x

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, continuous, r-factor

I would like to create boxplots of multiple variables for groups of a continuous x-variable. The boxplots should be arranged next to each other for each group of x.

The data looks like this:

```
require (ggplot2)
require (plyr)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(1234)
x   <- rnorm(100)
y.1 <- rnorm(100)
y.2 <- rnorm(100)
y.3 <- rnorm(100)
y.4 <- rnorm(100)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y.1,y.2,y.3,y.4))
```

which I then melted

```
dfmelt <- melt(df, measure.vars=2:5)
```

The facet_wrap as shown in this solution (
[Multiple plots by factor in ggplot (facets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987193/multiple-plots-by-factor-in-ggplot-facets))
gives me out each variable in an individual plot, but I would like to have the boxplots of each variable next to each other for each bin of x in one diagram.

```
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(value, x, group = round_any(x, 0.5), fill=variable))+
geom_boxplot() + 
geom_jitter() + 
facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image: fig1]

This shows the y-variables next to each other but does not bin x.

```
ggplot(dfmelt) +
geom_boxplot(aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))+
facet_grid(~variable)
```

[image: fig2]

Now I would like to produce such a plot for each bin of x.

What has to be changed or added?

Comment: Please include the libraries you're using in your code.  Also where is `round_any` coming from?

Comment: @TylerRinker - libraries are ggplot2 and plyr.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for. Is this close?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(x=factor(round_any(x,0.5)), y=value,fill=variable))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(.~variable)+
  labs(x="X (binned)")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.4,hjust=1))
```

**EDIT** (response to OP's comment)

You can put the Y's next to each other in each bin by just taking out the `facet_grid(...)` call, but I don't recommend it.

```
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(x=factor(round_any(x,0.5)), y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="X (binned)")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.4,hjust=1))
```

[image]

If you have to do it this way, it's still clearer using facets:

```
dfmelt$bin <- factor(round_any(dfmelt$x,0.5))
ggplot(dfmelt, aes(x=bin, y=value, fill=variable))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_grid(.~bin, scales="free")+
  labs(x="X (binned)")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

[image]

Note the addition of a `bin` column to `dfmelt`. This is because using `factor(round_any(x,0.5))` in the `facet_grid(...)` formula doesn't work.

Comment: this looks better, but is not what I want. For each bin of x I would like to have the corresponding y-boxplots next to each other (y1 | y2| y3| y4 for x1 and so on). Any ideas how that is possible?