# how to use ggplot facet to separate plots into sections of the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

I have a 18x3 data.frame. I would like a similar plot as in

[ggplot: arranging boxplots of multiple y-variables for each group of a continuous x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388845/ggplot-arranging-boxplots-of-multiple-y-variables-for-each-group-of-a-continuou)

but I want the x-axis divided into two variables (y0 & y1, y2 & y3, y4 & y5)

My best attempt was to add an additional factor column for the facet_wrap function, but it maintains all 6 variables in each plot.

```r
require (ggplot2) 
require (plyr) 
library(reshape2)
        
y.0 <- rnorm(3) 
y.1 <- rnorm(3) 
y.2 <- rnorm(3) 
y.3 <- rnorm(3) 
y.4 <- rnorm(3) 
y.5 <- rnorm(3)
        
df<- (as.data.frame(cbind(y.0, y.1, y.2, y.3, y.4, y.5)))

dfm <- melt(df, measure.vars = 1:6)
dfm$colour <- rep(c("no PM", "no PM", "no PM", "PM", "PM", "PM"), 3)
dfm$facet <- rep(c(rep("lys", 6), rep("lystrp", 6), rep("trplys", 6)))

ggplot(dfm, aes(x = variable,y = value, fill = colour)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(title = "Protease assay", x = "Sample type", y = "peptide count") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)) +   
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: plot]

Comment: Use `+facet_wrap(~facet,scales = "free_x")`

Comment: great, thanks, that worked!